# Cannot get attribute value as JSON when `Fiware-Service: tourguide` header is used

Tags: fiware-orion

We are testing how to get attributes values in the Tourguide application ( https://github.com/Fiware/tutorials.TourGuide-App) and it does not seem to work properly.

If we perform:

`curl -v <cb_host>:<cb_port>/v2/Entities/0115206c51f60b48b77e4c937835795c33bb953f/attrs/name/value -s -S --header 'Fiware-Service: tourguide'`

we get

`{"error":"NotAcceptable","description":"accepted MIME types: text/plain"}`

But if we perform:

`curl -v <cb_host>:<cb_port>/v2/Entities/0115206c51f60b48b77e4c937835795c33bb953f/attrs/name/value -s -S --header 'Fiware-Service: tourguide' --header 'Accept: text/plain'`

we get the expected value:

`Elizalde`

We tried to force the JSON response using:

`curl -v <cb_host>:<cb_port>/v2/Entities/0115206c51f60b48b77e4c937835795c33bb953f/attrs/name/value -s -S --header 'Fiware-Service: tourguide' --header 'Accept: application/json'`

but we get the same error:

`{"error":"NotAcceptable","description":"accepted MIME types: text/plain"}`

We have performed some additional tests.

We create the Bcn-Welt entity as described in https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/blob/develop/doc/apiary/v2/fiware-ngsiv2-reference.apib#L922

If we perform:

`curl -v <cb_host>:<cb_port>/v2/Entities/Bcn-Welt/attrs/humidity/value`

we get the expected value.

But, if we create the entity using the `Fiware-service: tourguide` header and perform the request again (using the `Fiware-Service: tourguide header`):

`curl -v <cb_host>:<cb_port>/v2/Entities/Bcn-Welt/attrs/humidity/value -s -S --header 'Fiware-Service: tourguide'`

we get:

`{"error":"NotAcceptable","description":"accepted MIME types: text/plain"}`

Information about the context broker version used

`{
  "orion" : {
  "version" : "1.1.0-next",
  "uptime" : "0 d, 2 h, 16 m, 2 s",
  "git_hash" : "2397fd46be54008409e7b2e4d29e572a2c598f2c",
  "compile_time" : "Tue May 24 10:38:00 UTC 2016",
  "compiled_by" : "root",
  "compiled_in" : "838a42ae8431"
}
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [NGSIv2 specification](http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/), at GET attribute value operation (`GET /v2/entities/entityId/attrs/attrName/value`):

> If response payload MIME type is application/json:
>
> - ...
> - If attribute value is a string, number, null or boolean, a HTTP error "406 Not Acceptable: accepted MIME types: text/plain" is returned.

So it seems that behaviour is as expected.

Side-note: you shouldn't use `/v2/Entities/...` in the URLs, but `/v2/entities` (lowercase 'E') as defined in the NGSIv2 specification.

Comment: Thanks, we will use another field for the cookbook example.

Comment: We have a doubt about the operation behaviour, if we use the header `Accept */*` the Context Broker tries to return an unsupported format:

GET /v2/Entities/Bcn-Welt/attrs/humidity/value HTTP/1.1
 User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
 Host: orion:1026
 Accept: */*
 
 HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable
 Connection: Keep-Alive
 Content-Length: 73
 Content-Type: application/json
 Fiware-Correlator: 11f9e63e-2324-11e6-9391-0242ac11000d
 Date: Thu, 26 May 2016 09:27:30 GMT
 
* Connection #0 to host orion left intact
{"error":"NotAcceptable","description":"accepted MIME types: text/plain"}

Comment: In order not to mix topics at SOF in the same post... could you ask that new doubt in a new question post, please? Thanks!